# read xml in UTF-8 in scala

Tags: xml, scala, encoding

I am trying to read a file to xml with the following code:

```
import scala.xml._

object HebrewToEnglishCityTranslator {

  val data = XML.loadFile("cities_hebrew_utf.xml");

  for(val entry <- data \\ "city") {
    val hebrewName = (entry \\ "hebrew_name").text
    val englishName = (entry \\ "english_name").text
    println(hebrewName + "=" + englishName)   }
```

However, my file is encoded in UTF-8 (hebrew chars) and XML encoding is `val encoding  = "ISO-8859-1"`

what should I do?

Comment: Is the first line of the XML file something like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`?

Comment: No - it is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: That `val encoding` is only used for saving, not for loading.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use `XML.load(reader: java.io.Reader)`, which allows you to specify the file encoding:

```
XML.load(new java.io.InputStreamReader(new java.io.FileInputStream("cities_hebrew_utf.xml"), "UTF-8"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the InputStream constructor instead of the String constructor.  Good explanation of Stream vs. Reader xml reading here: [Producing valid XML with Java and UTF-8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443305/producing-valid-xml-with-java-and-utf-8-encoding/443361#443361)