# Validating XML doc results in "Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence."

Tags: java, xml, saxon, schematron

I'm validating some XML files against [Schematron](http://schematron.com/) stylesheets by using [Probatron4j](http://www.probatron.org/probatron4j.html), which uses Saxon internally. Most of the time, this works fine, but occasionally, processing crashes with the error

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.

My research has shown that this message typically indicates (in no particular order)

- blatantly invalid data (e.g. attempting to read a ZIP file as if it were an XML file);
- the presence of [byte order marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark);
- the presence of characters that are not legal in UTF-8; or
- a document that is lying when it claims to be UTF-8-encoded.

None of these applies to the document I'm processing. I've inspected the input in byte array form during program execution, and it doesn't contain a BOM or any non-ASCII characters.

Processing gets about a fifth of the way through my 30kb doc before crashing on an unremarkable English sentence (by "unremarkable," I mean that all bytes are between 32 (space) and 122 (lowercase z); in other words, standard keyboard characters). The bytes of the supposedly offending element are at the end of this post.

Oddly, the failing document was generated by removing a few elements from a larger document that gets processed cleanly by the same code.

I know that the exception is being thrown in the `parse(InputSource input)` method of an object that implements the `org.xml.saxXMLReader` interface. According to [the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/XMLReader.html), `SAXException` indicates

> Any SAX exception, possibly wrapping another exception.

Examining the exception in a debugger shows that there is no wrapped exception.

What could be causing this error?

EDIT:

```
[60, 80, 97, 114, 97, 103, 114, 97, 112, 104, 62, 69, 120, 101, 99, 117, 116,
 105, 118, 101, 32, 83, 117, 109, 109, 97, 114, 121, 58, 32, 70, 114, 111, 109,
 32, 49, 55, 53, 52, 32, 116, 111, 32, 49, 55, 54, 51, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32,
 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 69, 117, 114, 111, 112, 101, 32, 97, 110, 100,
 32, 116, 104, 101, 32, 65, 109, 101, 114, 105, 99, 97, 115, 32, 119, 101, 114,
 101, 32, 99, 97, 117, 103, 104, 116, 32, 117, 112, 32, 105, 110, 32, 97, 32, 99,
 111, 110, 102, 108, 105, 99, 116, 32, 98, 101, 116, 119, 101, 101, 110, 32, 69,
 110, 103, 108, 97, 110, 100, 44, 32, 117, 110, 100, 101, 114, 32, 75, 105, 110,
 103, 32, 71, 101, 111, 114, 103, 101, 32, 73, 73, 44, 32, 97, 110, 100, 32, 70,
 114, 97, 110, 99, 101, 44, 32, 117, 110, 100, 101, 114, 32, 75, 105, 110, 103,
 32, 76, 111, 117, 105, 115, 32, 88, 86, 46, 32, 73, 110, 32, 69, 117, 114, 111,
 112, 101, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 116, 104, 105,
 115, 32, 112, 101, 114, 105, 111, 100, 32, 119, 97, 115, 32, 107, 110, 111, 119,
 110, 32, 97, 115, 32, 116, 104, 101, 32, 83, 101, 118, 101, 110, 32, 89, 101,
 97, 114, 115, 39, 32, 87, 97, 114, 59, 32, 105, 110, 32, 78, 111, 114, 116, 104,
 32, 65, 109, 101, 114, 105, 99, 97, 32, 105, 116, 32, 99, 97, 109, 101, 32, 116,
 111, 32, 98, 101, 32, 99, 97, 108, 108, 101, 100, 32, 116, 104, 101, 32, 70,
 114, 101, 110, 99, 104, 32, 97, 110, 100, 32, 73, 110, 100, 105, 97, 110, 32,
 87, 97, 114, 46, 32, 73, 116, 32, 119, 97, 115, 32, 97, 32, 99, 111, 110, 102,
 108, 105, 99, 116, 32, 111, 118, 101, 114, 13, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32,
 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 116, 114, 97, 100, 101, 32, 97, 110, 100, 32, 108, 97, 110,
 100, 46, 60, 47, 80, 97, 114, 97, 103, 114, 97, 112, 104, 62]
```

The exception is thrown after the third appearance of `109`.

Comment: Is it possible for you to edit the contents of that byte array into your post?

Comment: Just the part between the innermost tags, example ...`<iamatag>This is where it crashes</iamatag>`...

Comment: Do you know which character it throws the exception on in this array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've sort-of solved this. Even though Java uses UTF-8 internally for its `String` objects, the `String` class's `getBytes()` method will produce bytes in the system's default encoding unless you explicitly specify that you want UTF-8 (or some other encoding scheme that it understands).

I'm not completely sure how or why this solves the problem, since the bytes near the spot where the exception was thrown — the ones at the end of the question — were all valid UTF-8 bytes on their own, but it does seem to have fixed things.

The only potential cause I can think of for this is that I missed an invalid byte earlier in the file that screwed things up but didn't cause an immediate crash. I'm reading the bytes from a `ByteArrayInputStream`, so it's possible that the program read a big chunk from the buffer all at once, which set the `pos` marker to a spot beyond where the hypothetical bad character was located.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little googling while I waited for your byte array.

You said

> Oddly, the failing document was generated by removing a few elements from a larger document that gets processed cleanly by the same code.

[From that, I suspect the problem in this thread is probably your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443305/producing-valid-xml-with-java-and-utf-8-encoding)

Comment: Ah, yeah, I came across that issue earlier (although not that exact SO post). My input source is backed by a `ByteArrayInputStream`, not a `Reader`, so that's not it, but it was a good shot.