# How to convert byte[] from ANSI to UTF-8

Tags: java, xml, utf-8

```
byte[] data;
ResultSet resultSet 
data = resultSet.getBytes("xml");//It is XML of ANSI type from database(ms-sql);
```

I am trying to convert XML to UTF-8 type.

Please help me figure this out.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443305/producing-valid-xml-with-java-and-utf-8-encoding?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You *might* use the constructor of [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String%29) that takes an encoding; for example, `new String(data, "UTF-8");`

It's probably easiest to just call `resultSet.getString("xml");`

Answer (score 0):

You probably should just feed the bytes directly to an XML parser. XML almost requires the encoding to be specified, and the parser will figure it out on its own.